# How can I implement a UISlider in my SpriteKit game? [Swift 3]

Tags: swift3

I've searched for an updated guide on how to add UIKit elements to SpriteKit, and I haven't found anything that has worked. Specifically, I want to add a slider to the settings screen of my game show the current value of the slider in a label above it. Also, if the slider works, does that mean any UIKit element could be added successfully in the same way?

```
class Settings: SKScene {

//MARK: - Properties
var settingsLabel = SKLabelNode()
var backLabel = SKLabelNode()

var shipType1 = SKSpriteNode()
var shipType2 = SKSpriteNode()
var shipType3 = SKSpriteNode()
var shipType4 = SKSpriteNode()
var shipType5 = SKSpriteNode()
var shipArr: [SKSpriteNode] = []

var starCount = SKLabelNode()
var starCountLogo = SKSpriteNode()
var resetStars = SKLabelNode()
var resetHighScores = SKLabelNode()

//let slider: UISlider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -450, width: 200, height: 50)

//MARK: - didMove and willMove
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    settingsLabel = self.childNode(withName: "settingsLabel") as! SKLabelNode
    backLabel = self.childNode(withName: "backLabel") as! SKLabelNode

    shipType1 = self.childNode(withName: "shipType1") as! SKSpriteNode
    shipType2 = self.childNode(withName: "shipType2") as! SKSpriteNode
    shipType3 = self.childNode(withName: "shipType3") as! SKSpriteNode
    shipType4 = self.childNode(withName: "shipType4") as! SKSpriteNode
    shipType5 = self.childNode(withName: "shipType5") as! SKSpriteNode

    starCount = self.childNode(withName: "starCount") as! SKLabelNode
    starCountLogo = self.childNode(withName: "starCountLogo") as! SKSpriteNode
    resetStars = self.childNode(withName: "resetStars") as! SKLabelNode
    resetHighScores = self.childNode(withName: "resetHighScores") as! SKLabelNode

    shipArr = [shipType1, shipType2, shipType3, shipType4, shipType5]

    switch shipType {
    case .Spaceship1:
        resetTextures(node: shipType1, name: "Spaceship 1 Border")
    case .Spaceship2:
        resetTextures(node: shipType2, name: "Spaceship 2 Border")
    case .Spaceship3:
        resetTextures(node: shipType3, name: "Spaceship 3 Border")
    case .Spaceship4:
        resetTextures(node: shipType4, name: "Spaceship 4 Border")
    case .Spaceship5:
        resetTextures(node: shipType5, name: "Spaceship 5 Border")
    }

    let stars: Int = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "starNum") as! Int
    starCount.text = String(stars)
}

//MARK: - Touch Handling
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if backLabel.contains(location) {
            let transition: SKTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            let scene: SKScene = Menu(fileNamed: "Menu")!
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
        }
        else if resetStars.contains(location) {
            resetStars.run(pulseText)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: "starNum")
            starCount.text = "0"
            starNum = 0
        }
        else if resetHighScores.contains(location) {
            resetHighScores.run(pulseText)
            changeLeaderboard(whichScore: 0, toScore: 0)
        }
        else if shipType1.contains(location) {
            resetTextures(node: shipType1, name: "Spaceship 1 Border")
            shipType = .Spaceship1
        }
        else if shipType2.contains(location) {
            resetTextures(node: shipType2, name: "Spaceship 2 Border")
            shipType = .Spaceship2
        }
        else if shipType3.contains(location) {
            resetTextures(node: shipType3, name: "Spaceship 3 Border")
            shipType = .Spaceship3
        }
        else if shipType4.contains(location) {
            resetTextures(node: shipType4, name: "Spaceship 4 Border")
            shipType = .Spaceship4
        }
        else if shipType5.contains(location) {
            resetTextures(node: shipType5, name: "Spaceship 5 Border")
            shipType = .Spaceship5
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - Extra Functions
func fadeIn(node: SKNode, duration: Double) {
    let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: duration)
    node.run(fadeIn)
}

func fadeOut(node: SKNode, duration: Double) {
    let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: duration)
    node.run(fadeOut)
}

func changeTexture(node: SKSpriteNode, name: String) {
    node.texture = SKTexture(image: UIImage(named: name)!)
}

func resetTextures(node: SKSpriteNode, name: String) {
    var i = 1
    for spriteNode in shipArr {
        changeTexture(node: spriteNode, name: "Spaceship\(i)")
        i+=1
    }
    changeTexture(node: node, name: name)
}
```

}

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'Menu.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "Menu") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        return .allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

}